# Right-click options disappear on Dev-tool inspect mode chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, devtools, right-click, web-inspector

**Right-click options** disappear Dev-tool inspect mode chrome browser and they are not shown on Dev-tool browser. I have installed some chrome extensions and developed one recently. Besides, google chrome has a reverse image search option on the last versions when you right-click on elements of the web, like images. But when I open the devtool - inspect mode and right-click options are disappeared and show just limited options. Does anyone suggest a solution for it? As depicted in the below images.

**Without opining dev-tool (Developer inspect mode):**
[image]

**Developer inspect mode:**
[image]

Same question to google developer support:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/133948468/right-click-options-disappear-dev-tool-inspect-mode-chrome-browser-are-not-shown-on-dev-tool-inspect?hl=en&msgid=133948468

Answer (score 0):

The best answer could be to use shortcut keyboard to enable and disable JavaScript console as fast as possible

On the mac:
To open the console in Chrome, use this keyboard shortcut: **Cmd + Option + J** (on a Mac)

on Windows:
**Ctrl +Shift +J**